# Powershell - How to remove/filter element from JSON but keep the rest of it?

Tags: json, powershell

How do I remove all elements in the below JSON where 'Name = "Test HD Module 2" and Team = "Help Desk"?'

```
{
    "Content":  {
                    "Modules":  [
                                    {
                                        "ID":  2,
                                        "Name":  "Test HD Module 2",
                                        "Description": "This module opens the Google website.",
                                        "Team":  "Help Desk",
                                        "Is_Admin":  "No",
                                        "Location":  "Server",
                                        "Client_Facing":  "No",
                                        "Action":  "Website",
                                        "Image_Name":  "teamviewer",
                                        "Image_Path":  "C:Temp/Userss",
                                        "Is_Popup":  false,
                                        "Popup_Text":  "",
                                        "Submodule":  "false",
                                        "Is_Editable":  "true"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "ID":  3,
                                        "Name":  "Test HD Module 2",
                                        "Team":  "Server",
                                        "Description": "This module opens the website.",
                                        "Is_Admin":  "No",
                                        "Location":  "Server",
                                        "Client_Facing":  "No",
                                        "Action":  "Website",
                                        "Image_Name":  "device-info",
                                        "Image_Path":  "C:Temp/Userss",
                                        "Is_Popup":  true,
                                        "Popup_Text":  "Are you sure you want to run Test HD Module 3?",
                                        "Submodule":  "false",
                                        "Is_Editable":  "false"
                                    }
                                ],
                    "Sub-Modules":  [
                                        {
                                            "ID":  4,
                                            "Name":  "Test HD Sub-Module 3",
                                            "Team":  "Help Desk",
                                            "Is_Admin":  "No",
                                            "Location":  "Server",
                                            "Client_Facing":  "No",
                                            "Action":  "CMD",
                                            "Action_Text":  "",
                                            "Image_Name":  "device-info",
                                            "Image_Path":  "C:Temp/Users",
                                            "Is_Popup":  "false",
                                            "Popup_Text":  "",
                                            "Submodule":  "true",
                                            "Is_Editable":  "false"
                                        }
                                    ]
                }
}
```

I've tried using below but have had no luck.

```
$JSON | Where-Object {$_.Modules.Name -ne "Test HD Module 2" -and $_.Modules.Team -ne "Help Desk" }
```

Is there an easier way to filter a JSON? I basically want the same JSON but with those elements removed (I need to keep the 'Sub-Modules' information). Is the Where-Object the correct route when filtering a JSON?

Comment: I think you're looking for `$json.Content.Modules |? { -not ($_.Name -eq "Test HD Module 2" -and $_.Team -eq "Help Desk") }` tho, are you looking to "update" the object for latter converting it back to json ?

Comment: That is correct! I will "update" the object and convert it back to JSON. If that is the case, would the following syntax be what I need:


`ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 | Set-Content $JSONPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the expression you're looking for is:

```
-not ($_.Name -eq "Test HD Module 2" -and $_.Team -eq "Help Desk")
```

Different from the expression you currently have, which would for example, exclude any object where `Name != Test HD Module 2`.

If you want to update your object you can use the following:

```
$json = Get-Content path\to\myjson.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.Content.Modules = @(
    $json.Content.Modules | Where-Object {
        -not ($_.Name -eq "Test HD Module 2" -and $_.Team -eq "Help Desk")
    }
)
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 | Set-Content path\to\mynewjson.json
```

The [array subexpression operator `@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) ensures that the `Modules` property will become an array.

Resulting Json using the example in question would become:

```json
{
  "Content": {
    "Modules": [
      {
        "ID": 3,
        "Name": "Test HD Module 2",
        "Team": "Server",
        "Description": "This module opens the website.",
        "Is_Admin": "No",
        "Location": "Server",
        "Client_Facing": "No",
        "Action": "Website",
        "Image_Name": "device-info",
        "Image_Path": "C:Temp/Userss",
        "Is_Popup": true,
        "Popup_Text": "Are you sure you want to run Test HD Module 3?",
        "Submodule": "false",
        "Is_Editable": "false"
      }
    ],
    "Sub-Modules": [
      {
        "ID": 4,
        "Name": "Test HD Sub-Module 3",
        "Team": "Help Desk",
        "Is_Admin": "No",
        "Location": "Server",
        "Client_Facing": "No",
        "Action": "CMD",
        "Action_Text": "",
        "Image_Name": "device-info",
        "Image_Path": "C:Temp/Users",
        "Is_Popup": "false",
        "Popup_Text": "",
        "Submodule": "true",
        "Is_Editable": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```